# No puedo usar librerias en entorno virtual y Django

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

Tengo el siguiente problema, estoy usando un entorno virtual con Python, en el tengo instalados el framework de `Django` y las siguientes librerías:

- Pillow
- django-ckeditor
- django_rest_framework

Y otras más.

El caso es que puedo utilizar `django` perfectamente, **pero si quiero utilizar otras librerías no me deja, no encuentra las librerías.**

Estan todas instaladas correctamente en **INSTALLED_APPS(settings.py)**

Y al listar los módulos instalados en mi entorno con **pip list** me enseña que tengo los módulos correctamente instalados:

```
Package             Version
------------------- -------
asgiref             3.2.10
Django              3.1.2
django-ckeditor     6.0.0
django-filter       2.4.0
django-js-asset     1.2.2
djangorestframework 3.12.1
Markdown            3.3.3
Pillow              8.0.1
pip                 20.2.4
psycopg2-binary     2.8.6
pytz                2020.1
setuptools          50.3.2
sqlparse            0.4.1
wheel               0.35.1
```

Me salta el siguiente error si quiero usar `rest_framework` (se puede ver como esta activado el entorno virtual(Test1)):

```
(Test1) Davids-iMac:Test1 davidiriondopalacios$ /usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/davidiriondopalacios/Desktop/Enviroments/Test1/Test/user/serializers.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/davidiriondopalacios/Desktop/Enviroments/Test1/Test/user/serializers.py", line 1, in <module>
    from rest_framework import serializers
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_framework'
```

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'user',
    'rest_framework',
]
```

EDITADO:

No puedo llamar a `rest_framework`, pero si puedo hacer el migrate de las tablas de `rest_framework.auth.token`:

```
(Test1) Davids-iMac:Test davidiriondopalacios$ python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, authtoken, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying authtoken.0001_initial... OK
  Applying authtoken.0002_auto_20160226_1747... OK
  Applying authtoken.0003_tokenproxy... OK
(Test1) Davids-iMac:Test davidiriondopalacios$
```

No entiendo por que esta incoherencia.

Comment: Eso esta muy raro, ¿estas seguro que estas usando la versión correcta de Python? o ¿estas seguro que instalaste `djangorestframework` para la versión correcta de Python? (Te sugiero revisar [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33308781/django-rest-framework-no-module-named-rest-framework))

Comment: Sisi , he descubierto que el problema era que mi interprete de python que utilizaba en Visual Studio Code era otro distinto,este problema me pasaba en Ubuntu que es mi segundo ordenador, aqui supe arrglarlo ya que al crear un projecto de Django dentro del entorno virtual se agrega el interprete del entorno virtual, entonces ahi todo bien, el problema es que en Mac no pasa igual , al estar dentro de mi entorno virtual sigue usando el interprete general y no genera un nuevo interprete del entorno virtual como pasa en Ubuntu. Asi que el problema ahora es que VSC no utiliza el interprete de mi ENV